# KeyError in Weather API Response

Tags: python, keyerror, weather

I was making a python program which tells about weather but facing the following error

Please tell how to correct it?

**CODE**

```
import requests
import json

api = "<MY_API_KEY>"
BASE_URL = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?"
print("for which city?")
CITY = input("city?: ")
URL = BASE_URL + "q=" + CITY + "&appid=" + api

response = requests.get(URL)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = response.json()
    main = data['main']
    temperature = main['temp']
    humidity = main['humidity']
    pressure = main['pressure']
    report = data['weather']
    print(f"{CITY:-^30}")
    print(f"Temperature: {temperature}")
    print(f"Humidity: {humidity}")
    print(f"Pressure: {pressure}")
    print(f"Weather Report: {report[0]['description']}")
```

**TERMINAL**

```
PS C:\Users\mamta\Documents\PythonPanti\JARVISprj>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\mamta\Documents\PythonPanti\JARVISprj'; & 'C:\Users\mamta\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'c:\Users\mamta\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2021.5.842923320\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' 
'53873' '--' 'c:\Users\mamta\Documents\PythonPanti\JARVISprj\exp.py'
for which city?
city?: Delhi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mamta\Documents\PythonPanti\JARVISprj\exp.py", line 13, in <module>
    main = data['main']
KeyError: 'main'
```

Comment: Check your API Key, it seems to be invalid. Also, never share your API keys with anyone, especially not on a public forum like this

Comment: I'm not sure it's wise to share your API key. About the KeyError - it just tells you that there is no 'main' key in the response object. I suggest printing the 'data'.

Comment: @chmielcode I ran the query, it is an API Key error. Check out the response [here](https://imgur.com/a/54yCztT)

Comment: your code is the perfectly fine only problem here I see is when you enter any garbage value. [Notebook](https://imgur.com/a/iAZ9pNI)

Comment: ok thanks and thanks(you why twice)

Comment: @ArnavShukla moving to answer. Please close the question.

Comment: how to close it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly fine only problem here I see is when you enter any garbage value. You need to do error handling.
[image]